# On convex solids with all plane sections affine congruent

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, affine-geometry

**Question:** How many (classes of) convex 3D solids are there such that all non-degenerate planar sections of the solid are mutually affine congruent?

Further question: Same as above with 'projective' replacing 'affine'.

I can think of only the ellipsoid (all sections ellipses) as answer to both affine and projective cases of the question.

**Note:** Here is an earlier post that seems related (how closely I cannot decide):
[Convex body with affine-equivalent cross-sections](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/233365/convex-body-with-affine-equivalent-cross-sections)

Comment: Plane sections of a tetrahedron are *not* all triangles; you can also get quadrilaterals.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Corrected. Hope the question is now more meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with polyhedra and try to construct one whose sections are all polygons with the same number of sides.

Imagine standing a polyhedron (let's call it $P$) on a horizontal table on one of its vertices, and take a section parallel to the table very close to the vertex.

The section will be a polygon; the number of sides it has will be the same as the number of faces (or equivalently edges) meeting at that vertex.

We can choose any vertex to stand $P$ on; so number of faces meeting at each vertex must be the same; let's call this number $n$.

Now rest $P$ on the table on one of its faces. A horizontal section close to this face will be a polygon with the same number of edges as the face itself.

So all faces must be $n$-gons too.

Finally, balance $P$ on an edge. The horizontal section close to this edge will be a polygon with at least $4$ sides, so $n\ge 4$.

As usual, denote by $F,V,E$ the numbers of faces, vertices and edges of $P$ respectively.

Since $n$ faces meet at each vertex, $F=V$.

Since two $n$-gonal faces meet at every edge, $nF=2E$.

Using Euler's formula,
$$\begin{align}
F+V&=E+2 \\
F+F&=\frac{nF}{2}+2 \\
(4-n)F&=4 \end{align}$$

But since $n\ge 4$, this has no solutions and therefore there are no such polyhedra.

Comment: Thanks. Borrowing your idea, a shorter argument can be given: (1)choose any vertex to stand P on; so number of faces meeting at each vertex must be the same, say n. (2)  balance P on an edge. The horizontal section close to this edge should have n faces.  We readily have 2*n -2 = n (counting the number of faces meeting at each end vertex of that bottom edge of which 2 are shared). This gives n =2, which is impossible. 
.

Comment: Whatever the details, your answer settles the polyhedral case. What could be said about the smooth case?

Comment: I'm currently at the stage of picturing weird amoebas and wonky egg shapes. I'll check back if I think of something helpful! Meanwhile I might just stare at a lava lamp for a bit.